# Query in Laravel with Relationships from blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have the following tables

- `Users`
- `request`
- `servers`

Which are related in the following way.

- `User` has many `request`
- `Sever` has many `request`

Now what I want is to get all the servers associated with the requests that the user has without repetitions.

I have to do it in the blade view since in the view I am iterating the services and showing them in a table.

So far I've been trying the following

```
@foreach($requests as $request)    
@php
    $serversUser = \App\Server::where('requestsofservice', function($query){
    $query->where('user_id',$request->user->id);
    });
@endphp
@endforeach
```

But it doesn't work because of the variable `$request->user->id`.

and the result is

> Undefined variable: request

So, how could i get the services that the user a has related to their request  without repetitions.

***What happens is that as I am iterating the requests that I send from
the controller to the view, being inside the click foreach I get the
user and from that user all the servers that he has in his requests.***

Comment: And a best-practice comment: You shouldn't be doing queries in your view. You should be doing them in the controller.

Comment: @ceejayoz hou cant i do dat?

Comment: You'd do your foreaching in the controller and pass the entire post-processed `$requests` array to the view afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

`$request` doesn't exist in your function. Pass it by doing `function($query) use($request)`.

See PHP's documentation on variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

and on anonymous functions (in particular, the "Example #3 Inheriting variables from the parent scope" bit): http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php